# Fitting in a Model a beta distribution with within-subject variable involved: formula requested

Tags: r, glm, betareg

The distribution of my dependent variable called `st` follows the Beta distribution (visible through the command `descdist`). Now I have to create my model.
The only problem is that my experimental design is a 3x2, where I have an IV called `temp`, a factor with 3 levels measured within participants (the same participants at different time), and an IV called `cond`, a factor with 2 levels measured as a between-participants effect (two different groups). I want to see both main effects and interaction effects.
So far I have applied the `betareg()` formula for beta distribution after fitting the distribution with `fitdist()`. The only problem is that I don't know how in the `betareg()` formula I can indicate that my temp variable is **within** while my `cond` variable is **between** subjects. Can you help me out?

I tried to apply this formula:

```
MSTb=betareg(scaledst~temp*cond, data=ds.cy)
```

and then the ANOVA

```
Anova(MSTB)
```

It gives me a result but I think it doesn't considered the repeated measure situation.

Applying this formula instead doesn't work:

```
MSTb=betareg(scaledst~temp*cond+(1|id), data=ds.cy)
```

Where "id" is the Code of the participants to filter. It gives me this error: Error in

```
`contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  the contrast can be applied only to factors variable with 2 or more levels 
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(1, id) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
```

neither this one:

```
betareg(scaledst~temp*cond+(1+temp|id), data=ds.cy)

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(1, temp) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(1 + temp, id) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 1):

`betareg` doesn't handle mixed models/random effects, so its formula processor is getting confused. You could try `glmmTMB`:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
MSTb <- glmmTMB(scaledst~temp*cond+(1|id), data=ds.cy, family = beta_family)
```

Since `temp` is a within-subjects variable, and you have more than two levels (so the within-subject variation won't be confounded with the residual variation), you could try

```r
scaledst~temp*cond+(temp|id)
```

to account for among-subject variation in the *effect* of temperature.

I believe the `GLMMadaptive` and `brms` packages also handle mixed models with Beta-distributed responses (although the [Mixed Models task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html) is less clear on this than it might be ...)

---

PS it doesn't really make sense to use `descdist` and `fitdist` to characterize the *marginal* (overall) distribution of your response; you need to evaluate whether the *conditional* distribution of the data follows some particular assumed distribution sufficiently well ...

Comment: thanks again, I really appreciate the help you are giving me and I found it very helpful. I'm gonna then ask you, how can I apply an Anova() if I'm usign a glmmTMB function, cause I think it doesn't really apply and I need to see the variance and covariance based on my two factor. I don't really know if I made myself clear but I hope you gonna be able to me help me out again as usual